# Static variables in Python that are shared across files

Tags: python, static, singleton

I am pretty new to Python and I could't find a way to have static variables that are shared across different python files... In Java, it seems quite straight forward to do so... Here is what I'm trying to do:

***data.py***

```
class Shared(object):
    list_vars = []
    var = ""

    @staticmethod
    def print_vars():
        print "list_vars = " + str(Shared.list_vars)
        print "var = " + Shared.var
```

***user1.py***

```
import time
from data import Shared

Shared.list_vars.append("001")
time.sleep(5.0)
Shared.print_vars()

# It prints:
# list_vars = ['001']
# var =
```

***user2.py***

```
import time
from data import Shared

Shared.var = "002"
time.sleep(5.0)
Shared.print_vars()

# It prints:
# list_vars = []
# var = 002
```

Sorry, this may not be the best example but it catches the idea... my question is, if I want to have:

```
list_vars = ['001']
var = 002
```

in one of the/even some other python files or classes after running both user1.py and user2.py (I am considering user1.py and user2.py as two sub-programs in the same software package that are normally being run at the same time), what is the "Python way" to do so?

Thanks a lot!

**===============================**

**Updates for the question:**

To be a little more specific to the problem, please allow me to describe the problem in this way:

***data.py***

```
class Shared(object):
    list_vars = []
    var = ""

    @staticmethod
    def print_vars():
        print "list_vars = " + str(Shared.list_vars)
        print "var = " + Shared.var

    # Can be considered as a separate thread running in the background, waiting for messages
    @staticmethod
    def callback(message):
        if message.event == "add":
            Shared.list_vars.append(message.data)
        elif message.event == "remove" and message.data in Shared.list_vars:
            Shared.list_vars.remove(message.data)
```

There are two extra files, ***user1.py*** and ***user2.py***, their content can be ignored for the moment...

So let's say ***user1.py*** and ***user2.py*** are being run at about the same time, say time = 0.

- At time = 1, there is a message comes in (with message.event = "add"
  and message.data = "001"), the ***callback*** function in
  ***data.py*** is triggered and the ***"001"*** is added to the variable ***list_vars***.
- At time = 2, ***user1.py*** updates the variable ***var*** in
  ***data.py*** to ***"002"***.
- At time = 3, if ***user2.py*** wants to access and print out the
  variables ***list_vars*** and ***var***, with the latest values:

  - list_vars = ["001"]
  - var = 002

How can this be achieved in Python?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that (I suppose) you are launching separately `user1.py` and `user2.py`. So static values of class `Shared` are not preserved across different invocations.

But that's otherwise a perfectly correct way of sharing data : you declare classes or even variable in one file that is imported in the others.

But Python is not Java, and everything does not need to be a class. You could do :

- data.py

  ```py
  list_vars = []
  var = ""

  def print_vars():
      print "list_vars = " + str(Shared.list_vars)
      print "var = " + Shared.var
  ```
- user1.py

  ```
  import time
  import data as shared

  shared.list_vars.append("001")
  time.sleep(5.0)
  shared.print_vars()

  # It prints:
  # list_vars = ['001']
  # var =
  ```
- user2.py

  ```
  import time
  import data as shared

  shared.var = "002"
  time.sleep(5.0)
  shared.print_vars()

  # It prints:
  # list_vars = []
  # var = 002
  ```
- main.py

  ```
  import user1
  # It prints:
  # list_vars = ['001']
  # var =
  import user2
  # It prints:
  # list_vars = ['001']
  # var = 002
  ```

Comment: Hi Serge Ballesta, thank you for your answer, that solves the problem I described in the example. Actually the example I had given may not accurately describe the problem I am facing, so please excuse me, if you have time, could you also have a look at the updates at the bottom of the question? Many thanks!

Comment: @Fujiolydak : provided all the scripts are run in the same process, they will correctly share the data. The only problem if there are different threads is that you could need to synchronize accesses to the shared data.